# Compile / Cobine 2 or more JS files into 1

Tags: javascript

Right now I am working on a framework which has a lot of javascript. 
I am using EM6 as the JS standards along with http://prepros.io app for windows to compile with babel

However, I am not sure how to compile/combine 2 JS files into 1 like some major frameworks do, e.g. Bootstrap. I checked their code. But I am confused.

Any help would be really appreciated..

Tried with this code:

source1.js

```
const Alert = ( ($) => {
    class Alert {
        constructor(element) {
            this._element = element
        }
    }

    return Alert
} )( $ )

export default Alert
```

final.js

```
import Alert from './source1'

( ($) => {
    const version = $.fn.jquery.split( ' ' )[ 0 ].split( '.' )
} )( $ )

export {
    Alert,
}
```

Output i get

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.Alert = undefined;

var _alert = require('./imports/alert');

var _alert2 = _interopRequireDefault(_alert);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

(function ($) {
    var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.');
})($);

exports.Alert = _alert2.default;
```

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/ ?

Comment: @Tareq i am new to this and have no idea who to use it.

Comment: Try to take a look at a tutorial. Ex: https://medium.com/javascript-training/beginner-s-guide-to-webpack-b1f1a3638460

Comment: I would consider not doing this.  Having the source in different files for a large JS application can be very beneficial.  However, there are build process (post-build) that can do this.  https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat

Comment: @Tareq thanks for that. since i am backend developer. i am looking for some thing like an application that i can run in my windows.